# Converting Facebook created_time to TDateTime in Delphi

Tags: facebook, delphi, datetime, facebook-graph-api, delphi-xe8

I am using Facebook graph API in my application. Facebook API returns an array of objects as response. For each item in the array, there is an object **created_time** which denotes the time of post. I need to convert that datetime into Delphi TDateTime so that I can have mm/dd//yy hh:mm:ss format time.

ArrayItem:

```
 {
         "created_time": "2015-10-12T01:56:25+0000",
         "link": "http://exampleeeeee.com",
         "id": "349561906753_10154021323131754"
      }
```

By the way Facebook returns the datetime in other format as well but I am eager to learn this.

Comment: Seems easy to parse. I'm assuming that's October 12th 2015 at 1:56am and 25 seconds. Not sure what the 0000 is, at first I thought milliseconds, but don't know.

Comment: @Rabi Do you know the date format used by Facebook? I believe that it is documented what it is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The format is  ISO 8601. Here is an example. http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime .

Comment: The `+0000` is a timezone offset, which is added to the specified time. In this case, the offset is 0, which means the final time is represented in UTC.

Comment: Indy's `StrInternetToDateTime()` and `GMTToLocalDateTime()` functions can parse this format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The date format is ISO 8601 and you can convert it using the `XMLTimeToDateTime` function in the  [XSBuiltIns](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/XSBuiltIns.html) unit.

```
uses
  XSBuiltIns;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ISO8601StrA, ISO8601StrB: String;
  Dt: TDateTime;
begin
  ISO8601StrA := '2015-10-12T01:56:25+0000';
  Dt := XMLTimeToDateTime(ISO8601StrA);
  ISO8601StrB := DateTimeToXMLTime(Dt, False);
end;
```

Comment: This `with` always gives me a headache :-/